# PayPal Rest API Create Payment Not Returning the Sale Id

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to execute a credit card payment with PayPal's rest API (sandbox). Here's the code:

```
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
...

try {
    $payment->create($this->apiContext);

    $saleId = $payment->getTransactions()[0]->getRelatedResources()[0]->getSale()->getId();
} catch (PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    ...
}
```

This sends the following JSON:

> {"experience_profile_id":"XX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX","intent":"sale","payer":{"payer_info":{"first_name":"Jim","last_name":"Smith","email":"someone@somewhere.com","phone":""},"payment_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"credit_card":{"first_name":"Jim","last_name":"Smith","number":"XXXXXXXXXXXX4487","type":"visa","expire_month":"06","expire_year":"2020","cvv2":"123","billing_address":{"line1":"123
>   Test Street","line2":"","city":"Test
>   City","state":"","postal_code":"XXXX
>   XXX","country_code":"GB"}}}]},"transactions":[{"amount":{"currency":"GBP","total":"13.50","details":{"shipping":"3.50","tax":"1.67","subtotal":"8.33"}},"item_list":{"items":[{"name":"T-Shirt
>   Black
>   Small","currency":"GBP","quantity":"1","sku":"abc123","price":"8.33"}],"shipping_address":{"recipient_name":"Jim
>   Smith","line1":"123 Test Street","line2":"","city":"Test
>   City","state":"Some State","postal_code":"XXXX
>   XXX","country_code":"GB"}},"description":"Payment
>   details","invoice_number":"XXXXX"}]}

This was working fine until recently, however now it doesn't return anything for the related resources. here's the json I am getting back:

> {"id":"PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","create_time":"2016-06-20T11:45:28Z","update_time":"2016-06-20T11:45:28Z","state":"created","intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"credit_card":{"type":"visa","number":"xxxxxxxxxxxx4487","expire_month":"6","expire_year":"2020","first_name":"Jim","last_name":"Smith","billing_address":{"line1":"123
>   Test Street","city":"Test City","postal_code":"XXXX
>   XXX","country_code":"GB"}}}]},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"13.50","currency":"GBP","details":{"subtotal":"8.33","tax":"1.67","shipping":"3.50"}},"description":"Payment
>   details","item_list":{"items":[{"name":"T-Shirt Black
>   Small","sku":"abc123","price":"8.33","currency":"GBP","quantity":"1"}],"shipping_address":{"recipient_name":"Jim
>   Smith","line1":"123 Test Street","city":"Test City","state":"Some
>   State","postal_code":"XXXX
>   XXX","country_code":"GB"}},"related_resources":[]}],"links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","rel":"self","method":"GET"}]}

Please note I'm using version 1.7.2 of the API and I have recently upgraded to PHP version 7.

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You need to put up the error logs as well, and specify the setups of your integration e.g. endpoint set to sandbox or live? what's in the response of your PAY api call..

Comment: @pp_pduan I have updated the question stating that I am using the sandbox and the json response I am getting back. As you can see the related_resources is empty. I hope this helps.

Comment: version 1.7.2??? Does such version number exist?, the current version is 204

Comment: @SML I'm going by the latest version on composer. https://packagist.org/packages/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

Comment: I see, so the problem only started after upgrading to PHP version 7, correct? What version were you using before then?

Comment: It's a little difficult to say because I've been working on building in direct payments (payment method = "credit_card"). Before I only supported the "paypal" payment method. My current version which is live is 1.5.1. I may have originally built my direct payment support on top of that. As for PHP 7 that was done quite recently aswell as I didn't expect it to have an impact. I'll have a quick test with version 1.5.1.

Comment: @SML just tested this with version 1.5.1 and I got the same response back. I'll play around with different versions. If anyone has any other suggestions I'd be grateful. Please note from the json above that the related resources are not being returned.

Comment: Try $saleId=Sale::get($payment->getTransactions()[0]->getRelatedResources()[0]->getSale()->getId(),$apiContext);
   >

Comment: sorry missed the part about related_resources being empty. can you include your full code starting from $payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
 to the end of the file?

Comment: @SML I have added the JSON that it sends to the question.

Comment: Did you try to first figure out if it is really caused by PHP 7? Is it possible to reinstall an old version of PHP and verify it works?  Just want to first identify if it is a code problem or a PHP 7 problem, or even a PayPal problem

Comment: @Peter I've just tested this in PHP 5.6 (the version I used before) and I got the same response. I kind of expected this though because I am simply echoing the response returned from PayPal's API server. I'm going to have to give up on this soon as I've already spent a while and my thought is PayPal have changed their API so it no longer works in the sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to get this working although from no fault of my own. It appears my sandbox buyer account is no longer working. I found the following document:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php

This worked fine so I played a game of spot the different and the only thing which helped resolve the issue was using the card details in their sample. I've already spent some considerable time on this problem so I'm going to accept that it's working fine and hopefully I won't run into any issues during production.

Comment: Thanks @nfplee I am really confused at the moment about the flow of paypal implementation user experience.